# How can I access (in effect) 'an array' of element ids through jQuery? i.e. #photograph_1 #photograph_2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to access several element ids using jQuery, so I can dynamically alter the contents of these elements. However, (I believe) I am unable to use nth-child selectors, as these element ids do not all share the same parent, as they use a table layout.

For example,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <div class="bio"><img id="photograph_1" src="test.jpg"></div> </td>
        <td> <div class="bio"><img id="photograph_2" src="test.jpg"></div> </td>                       
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <div class="bio"><img id="photograph_3" src="test.jpg"></div> </td>
        <td> <div class="bio"><img id="photograph_4" src="test.jpg"></div> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I assumed there would be a way to access each element by its id, as `$('#photograph_1')` however when I try to do this dynamically it does not work. `for(i=0; i++; i<4) { $('#photograph_'+(i+1)).attr('src',image[i]); }` (image[] is an array of image sources).

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how can it be done?  From [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp), I am not clear what to do.

Answer (score 2):

fix your for statement

it should be

```
for (var i = 0;i < 4; i++ )
```

not

```
for(i=0; i++; i<4)
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>
> statement

You were using i++ as the condition

Comment: @tymeJV lol yeah.. still really early in the morning.  I didn't see it either until I tried to do a jsfiddle and was wondering why it wasn't working

Comment: Haha dangit ;) Always the way, eh? I agree, coffee time! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop will work fine, you're forgetting the `#` in your selector. Try

```
for(i=1; i <= 4; i++) { $('#photograph_'+i).attr('src',image[i]); }
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I miscopied some of my code over... I do include the `#` in my working code. Apologies.

Comment: Should still work...when is this code snippet being run? Any errors in the console?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working... No errors. I'm just running it when `$(document).ready( function() { //Runs here } );`

Comment: See wirey's answer, ahh so simple!